# Using Matlab to solve a system of ODEs using Euler's method

Tags: matlab, ode

I have created a function Euler.m to solve a a system of ODEs using Euler's method. I wish to use this function to solve the system of ODEs defined by the anonymous function `func=@(t) ([x(t)+4*y(t)-exp(t);x(t)+y(t)+2*exp(t)])` with initial conditions given by `y0`.

```
func=@(t) ([x(t)+4*y(t)-exp(t);x(t)+y(t)+2*exp(t)]);
y0=[4;5/4];
y_exact=@(t) [4*exp(3*t)+2*exp(-t)-2*exp(t);2*exp(3*t)-exp(-t)+exp(t)/4]; %exact solution of ODEs
a=0; % such that 
b=1; % a<t<b
N=120;
[t,y] = Euler(func,a,b,y0,N)
```

However, the following error is displayed:

"Error using solution>@(t)([x(t)+4*y(t)-exp(t);x(t)+y(t)+2*exp(t)])
Too many input arguments.

Error in solution (line 7)
[t,y] = Euler(func,a,b,y0,N)".

Why is this error being displayed?

Comment: The error is that you are giving too many inputs to `func` on line 7 of the function `Euler`. But you can't expect an answer if you don't include the code for your `Euler` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretending that you already know when writing the ODE function `func` what the solutions `x(t),y(t)` are. Then you are going to compute solutions approximations for it. This is completely the wrong way around.

The function for the right side is just for a point in phase space, so you need

```
func=@(t,y) ([y(1)+4*y(2)-exp(t);y(1)+y(2)+2*exp(t)]);
```

where the input `y` is a two-component vector.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. Can this then be graphed? I have used the commands: `tplot=linspace(a,b);
yv=y_exact(tplot);
plot(tplot,y,tplot,yv,'r');`, but the error "Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length" is displayed.

Comment: Try `plot(t,y,tplot,yv,'r');` so that the Euler plot uses the times corresponding to the Euler points.